# How to list all the parathreads in a Polkadot network?

Tags: parachain, rococo, parathread

I want to get the list of **Parathreads** in my network.

In this previous question: [How to list all the parachains in a Polkadot network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766718/how-to-list-all-the-parachains-in-a-polkadot-network) it explains how to get a list of all parachains in the relay chain, querying the storage Parachains.

If I query the [ParaLifecycles](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/264b81abe854646b4f98f34b711deb0cf96f1ea3/runtime/parachains/src/paras/mod.rs#L567) storage I get the whole list of Para IDs (Parachains and Parathreads) and in my app I can filter this list to have only the parathreads list. But is there a better way to get only the list of **Parathreads**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are already following the best approach one could use at the moment, because [`Paras`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/7a54fd6e0b38ce69b320f1d1825ea47888f13291/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L186) in `paras_registrar` keeps every registered paraId along with its `ParaInfo`, but then you won't be able to filter which of those are parathreads / parachains.